# How To Populate objects inside array through aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i got order document with array contains objects, each one contains product id and quantity and also options related to product,
what i would to achieve is to join this collection with product collection through aggregation to get certain product data like name, price, image

this is the order document i would like to aggregate

```
{
_id:ObjectId('61c45d25bdf9c1389879db9f'),
orderItems: [
    {
        options:[
            {
                _id:ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            },
        ],
        quantity:4,
        product:ObjectId('61c5e1e7c2ec39450cdf41b7')
    }, {
        options:[
            {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer:'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            },
            {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer:'lorem'
            },
        ],
        quantity:3,
        product:ObjectId('61c5e1e7c2ec39450cdf41b7')
    }
]}
```

this is final query I'd like to achieve

```
{
    _id:ObjectId('61c45d25bdf9c1389879db9f'),
    orderItems: [
        {
            options:[
                {
                    _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                    question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                    answer:'lorem'
                },
                {
                    _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                    question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                    answer:'lorem'
                }, {
                    _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                    question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                    answer: 'lorem'
                }, {
                    _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                    question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                    answer: 'lorem'
            },
        ],
        quantity:2,
        product: {
            name:'lorem ipsum dolor set',
            image:'1452877_product.png',
            type:'immo file',
            price:20
        }
    }, {
        options:[
            {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            },
            {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer:'lorem'
            }, {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            },
            {
                _id: ObjectId('61fd914d4a236b94f816c27d'),
                question: 'lorem ipsum dolor set amet',
                answer: 'lorem'
            },
        ],
        quantity: 3,
        product: {
            name: 'lorem ipsum dolor set',
            image: '1452877_product.png',
            type: 'immo file',
            price: 20
        }
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution that worked for me is to unwind the orderItems first then join the products collection using lookup and then use group at last

the code as follow

```
const orders = await Order.aggregate([
     {
            $unwind:'$orderItems'
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from:'products',
                let:{productId:"$orderItems.product"},
                pipeline:[
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr:{
                                $eq:["$_id", "$$productId"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $project:{
                            name:1,
                            price:1,
                            type:1,
                            image:1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as:"product"
            }
        },
        {
            $set:{"orderItems.product":"$product"}
        },
        {
            $unwind:"$orderItems.product"
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id:"$_id",
                orderItems:{$push:"$orderItems"}
            }
        }
])
```